# Unable to crop header image in my custom theme for wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

From today I started to learn custom theme development for wordpress, and I'm currently stuck with the problem that shows a error when I try to crop the image for the header. Here is the sample code below.

(1. I had set the hook for the header image the functions.php

```
add_theme_support('custom-header');
```

(2. Set the image inside the header.php

```
   <img class="myhead" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php get_custom_header()->height ?>"
             width="<?php get_custom_header()->width ?>" alt="">
```

(3.Tested if the image will be displayed inside the header. The image was  displayed in the actual size.

How will I able to customize the header image in the Customize ? I would love to hear from you.

Comment: which theme are you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex-width` & `flex-height`are adjust itself,

```
 $args = array(
        'flex-width'    => true,
        'width'         => 980,
        'flex-height'    => true,
        'height'        => 200,
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

Update you header.php

```
<img alt="" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" />
```